# I have just installed and updated Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I can't get my Broadcom 4311 wifi to turn on

Tags: wireless

I read other questions indicating the same issue and followed the instructions given. The results of the script that I ran on my system are at the link below.
BTW. Ubuntu will not turn power off on my laptop either.
I have a Compaq Presario V5205NR

http://paste.ubuntu.com/9842937/

Answer (score 1):

Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

Detach the ethernet, reboot and tell us if it's working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using unity, cause if you are i know of a bug that causes wifi controls in the gui to malfunction if you are using multiple adapters or certain wireless adapters. Run these commands to get an alternative wireless manager called wicd
`sudo su
apt-get update
apt-get install wicd`
Note: i am not sure of the package name so if it does not work search for the package (.deb file) online and install it from there. (open it with software center) or search it up on software center.